# Output/Displaying the value in the HTML

Tags: javascript

So I am a newbie and I am just practice

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("input-text");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

function displayOutput(text) {
  output.textContent = text;
}

function getUserInput() {
  return userInput.value;
}

function addValue() {
  const enteredValue = getUserInput();
  const displayValue = enteredValue;
  displayOutput(displayValue);
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addValue);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="input-text">
  <button id="add">add value</button>
</form>
<p>Data: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

my first lesson of JS is function and with .textcontent. So I wrote a code that will output the value/ number I entered on the input field after I click the add value button but somehow my code doesn't work.

> DISCLAIMER> I HAVENT LEARN LOOPS< IF STATEMENTS OR WHATSOEVER I just want to practice my lesson.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Check whether you are having some value in text, also try using innerHTML instead of textContent.

Comment: Your button is a submit button, and you did not prevent the default form submission in your click handler - so your form submits, and reloads the current page. Add `type="button"` on the `button` element.

Comment: "Doesn't work"? Let us know what error occured and so on..
Did you add the js before the html? Because then it tries to ge the elements before they are event there ;)

Comment: @CBroe, Thank you I think that is what my problem there.

Comment: @sandrooco, it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submission and reload the page. It is the default behavior, so you need to prevent this behavior.

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("input-text");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

function displayOutput(text) {
  output.textContent = text;
}

function getUserInput() {
  return userInput.value;
}

function addValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const enteredValue = getUserInput();
  const displayValue = enteredValue;
  displayOutput(displayValue);
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addValue);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="input-text">
  <button id="add">add value</button>
</form>
<p>Data: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like some other people already mentioned, it's the `<form>` that's being submitted.

I'd recommend removing the `<form></form>` since there no use for it now:

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("input-text");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

function displayOutput(text) {
  output.textContent = text;
}

function getUserInput() {
  return userInput.value;
}

function addValue() {
  const enteredValue = getUserInput();
  const displayValue = enteredValue;
  displayOutput(displayValue);
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-text">
<button id="add">add value</button>

<p>Data: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

---

Small side-note:

```js
function addValue() {
  const enteredValue = getUserInput();
  const displayValue = enteredValue;
  displayOutput(displayValue);
}
```

Can be simplified to just:

```
function addValue() {
    displayOutput(getUserInput());
);
```

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("input-text");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

function displayOutput(text) {
  output.textContent = text;
}

function getUserInput() {
  return userInput.value;
}

function addValue() {
  displayOutput(getUserInput());
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-text">
<button id="add">add value</button>

<p>Data: <span id="output"></span></p>
```